# Creating a Tensorflow batched dataset object from a CSV containing multiple labels and features

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tensorflow

I have a CSV dataset containing N features and M labels. It is large-enough that I can't just put it all in memory, so I'm hoping to read it into Tensorflow (2.0.0) by chunks. Everything in the table has the same data-type (float), and all features and labels are uniquely named. Visualized:

```
| F1   | F2   | ... | FN   | L1   | L2   | ... | LM   |
|------|------|-----|------|------|------|-----|------|
| 1.0  | 2.0  | ... | 3.0  | 4.0  | 5.0  | ... | 6.0  |
| 7.0  | 8.0  | ... | 9.0  | 10.0 | 11.0 | ... | 12.0 |
| 13.0 | 14.0 | ... | 15.0 | 16.0 | 17.0 | ... | 18.0 |
| ...  | ...  | ... | ...  | ...  | ...  | ... | ...  |
| 19.0 | 20.0 | ... | 21.0 | 22.0 | 23.0 | ... | 24.0 |
```

My goal here is to load this CSV data into a tensorflow dataset object, with all of my features and labels. So far, my best guess has been to use Tensorflow's built-in make_csv_dataset function. Using a list of labels in `labels`, I tried this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
data = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset("data.csv", batch_size=32, num_epochs=100, label_name=labels)
```

Which leads to a ValueError indicating that the label_name argument must correspond to one of the columns. The documentation also indicates that this is a string corresponding to a single label.

All of the documentation and every example I've found out there for loading a CSV in chunks seems to only focus on situations where a single label is to be predicted. Even the TensorFlow guide on loading CSV data (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) only has a single label in its example.

This seems like a common-enough operation that I shouldn't need to write a custom dataset class. What's the ideal (or generally-accepted) way of generating a Tensorflow dataset object from a CSV?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tutorial instead:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe

Load csv file to pandas dataframe first. Then select the required columns from df into subframes of 'features' and 'targets'. After passing target.values thru 'from_tensor_slices', it will become one tensor of labels, as required by tf.

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
feature = df['F1']
target  = df[['L1', 'L2']]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((feature.values, target.values))
for feat, targ in dataset.take(1):
    print ('Features: {}, Target: {}'.format(feat, targ))
```